# Joda - Print DateTime ignoring TimeZones

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I got two timestamps:

- `2015-03-30T00:36:00.000+0100`
- `2015-03-30T00:36:00.000+0200`

Only the timezone differs. After parsing this timestamp with `DateTimeFormatter` and printing only the time (without date) using `DateTimeFormat.shortTime()`. 
The results are:

- **00:36**
- **23:36**

Since only the times matter in my case I would like to ignore those timezones when printing the time. How can I achieve printing **00:36** for both timestamps?

Comment: Did you mean http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone- or http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZoneRetainFields-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-

Comment: @DawidPura The OP is not interested in the offset so using `DateTime` is not right - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a fixed-length-format so you can simply do this:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser());
System.out.println(ldt.toLocalTime().toString(ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinute()));
// output: 00:36
```

I use `LocalDateTime` because you are not interested in the timezone offset.

Comment: Seems a bit hacky to me. But you pointed me in the right direction. DTF.parseLocalDateTime does the job.

Comment: @Sebastian You are right, see my update. I have found out that there exists a predefined formatter which uses an optional offset part (not so clear by name).